# Kotlin Signal Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to create a flow that signals to my Android app to upload data to the network. The data is being stored in a SQLite DB and would be uploaded in batches. There are 3 different ways to trigger this upload:

1. Whenever the DB hits the batch size
2. On a timer after X seconds
3. Directly triggered from something else in the app (e.g. a navigation event)

My flow then looks like a merge of `SharedFlow<Unit>`

```kotlin
private val databaseFlow = dataSource.getEventBatchStream(batchSize)
private val timerFlow = TickerFlowFactory().createTickerFlow()
private val userRequestFlow: MutableStateFlow<Unit> = MutableStateFlow(Unit)

saveJob = scope.launch {
  merge(databaseFlow, timerFlow, userRequestFlow)
  .collectLatest {
    saveEventBatch(dataSource.getEventBatch(batchSize))
  }
}
```

It seems because of conflation, events are being dropped. I've been able to solve this by using a channel like so

```kotlin
private val databaseFlow = dataSource.getEventBatchStream(batchSize)
private val timerFlow = TickerFlowFactory().createTickerFlow()
private val requestToSaveChannel = Channel<Unit>() // Here's the channel

timerJob = scope.launch {
  timerFlow.collect { requestToSaveChannel.send(Unit) }
}

dbJob = scope.launch {
  databaseFlow
    .filter { it.size == batchSize }
    .collect { requestToSaveChannel.send(Unit) }
}

saveJob = scope.launch {
  requestToSaveChannel.receiveAsFlow()
    .collect { savePeteEventBatch(dataSource.getEventBatch(batchSize)) }
}
```

[image]

This works, but seems wrong idiomatically and I feel like there should be a solution using only flows but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible issues, depending on what's the behavior you expect.

1. Your `userRequestFlow` is a `MutableStateFlow<Unit>` which is essentially a noop, because `StateFlow` doesn't emit an event when you give it something that's equal to its `value`. So switching to `MutableSharedFlow` is a must here.
2. If the issue is that there's always an event before `collectLatest` completes, you need to use `collect` and `conflate` like so:

```
private val databaseFlow = dataSource.getEventBatchStream(batchSize)
private val timerFlow = TickerFlowFactory().createTickerFlow()
private val userRequestFlow: MutableSharedFlow<Unit> = MutableSharedFlow(Unit)

saveJob = scope.launch {
  merge(databaseFlow, timerFlow, userRequestFlow)
    .conflate()
    .collect {
      saveEventBatch(dataSource.getEventBatch(batchSize))
    }
}
```

The `conflate` operators drops emitted values while waiting for `collect` to finish, but keeps the latest value in a buffer. So once `collect` finishes, if there was at least one event produced during the time, it'll run the `saveEventBatch` again. If no event was produced, it'll wait for the next one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this will work or not but it worth a try...

My first thought was to filter the `private val databaseFlow = dataSource.getEventBatchStream(batchSize)` to ensure that the batches of the correct sizes are triggered only, then add a delay to prevent conflation

So it will look like this :

```kotlin
private val databaseFlow = dataSource.getEventBatchStream(batchSize)
    .filter { it.size == batchSize }
    .onEach { delay(1) } // Add a slight delay to prevent conflation

private val timerFlow = TickerFlowFactory().createTickerFlow()

private val userRequestFlow: MutableSharedFlow<Unit> = MutableSharedFlow()
```

Then we can use [buffer](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/buffer.html) to ensure that only the latest event is kept in the buffer, preventing unnecessary backpressure and avoiding dropping events.

**but** there is another extension function that is called [flatMapLatest](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html) which returns a flow that switches to a new flow produced by transform function every time the original flow emits a value **and** it is buffered by default

We can use it.

an example of its usage in your scenario is like this :

```kotlin
saveJob = scope.launch {
    flatMapLatest(databaseFlow, timerFlow, userRequestFlow) { _ ->
        flow { emit(dataSource.getEventBatch(batchSize)) }
    }.collect { batch ->
        saveEventBatch(batch)
    }
}
```

Here we used the [flatMapLatest](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html) to emit the event batches every time any of the other flows emit a value then we save it

- Monitoring Multiple Flows: flatMapLatest acts as a "flow merger" that continuously monitors all three flows: databaseFlow, timerFlow, and userRequestFlow.
- Reacting to the Latest Emission: As soon as any of these flows emit a value, flatMapLatest immediately takes action. It cancels any ongoing emissions from previous flows and focuses solely on the latest one.
- Triggering Batch Fetching: For the flow that emitted the value, flatMapLatest executes the provided lambda: `flow { emit(dataSource.getEventBatch(batchSize)) }`. This creates a new flow that fetches the event batch from the data source.
- Saving the Batch: The newly created flow, which emits the fetched batch, is then collected using collect. Within collect, the saveEventBatch function is called to persist the batch to the network.

**Key Point**: [flatMapLatest](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html) ensures that only the most recent batch, triggered by any of the three flows, is processed and saved. This prevents conflation and ensures that events aren't accidentally dropped or overwritten.

I really hope this works because I spent about an hour searching for this information

Please keep me updated whether this worked or not :)